# Terraform multiple cloudwatch events trigger same lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup the following in Terraform. So two event rules, start_event at 8am and stop_event at 6pm.

```
# Create cloudwatch event rules
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "stop_ec2_event_rule" {
  name        = "stop-ec2-event-rule"
  description = "Stop EC2 instance at a specified time each day"
  schedule_expression = var.cloudwatch_schedule_stop
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "start_ec2_event_rule" {
  name        = "start-ec2-event-rule"
  description = "Start EC2 instance at a specified time each day"
  schedule_expression = var.cloudwatch_schedule_start
}
```

Each event passes an action to the lambda

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "stop_ec2_event_rule_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.stop_ec2_event_rule.name
  target_id = "TriggerLambdaFunction"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.arn
  input     = "{\"environment\":\"${var.environment}\", \"action\":\"stop\"}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "start_ec2_event_rule_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_ec2_event_rule.name
  target_id = "TriggerLambdaFunction"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.arn
  input     = "{\"environment\":\"${var.environment}\", \"action\":\"start\"}"
}
```

This works

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.stop_ec2_event_rule.arn
```

This issue I'm facing is that I cannot get Terraform to associate the start_event with the lambda function. I go into the AWS console and I can manually add the CloudWatch start_event trigger to the lambda function.

If I have the start_event resources

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_ec2_event_rule.arn
```

It will complain that the statement_id is duplicated.

I needed something like the terraform aws_lambda_event_source_mapping but that only allows Lambda functions to get events from Kinesis, DynamoDB and SQS; and not a CloudWatch event.

How can I tell terraform to associate multiple cloudwatch events to the same lambda function; when I can manually do it from the AWS console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`statement_id` is **not compulsory**, so you can safely omit it from your `aws_lambda_permission` and terraform will unique generate id for you automatically. You can also use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/count.html) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/for_each.html) to save you some typing for `aws_lambda_permission`.

For example, using `for_each` you could define `aws_lambda_permission` to be:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch" {
  
  for_each      = {for idx, v in [
      aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.stop_ec2_event_rule,
      aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_ec2_event_rule
  ]: idx => v}
  
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = each.value.arn
}
```

Analogical versions could be written for `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` and  `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` so that your code is based on `for_each` or `count` without the copy-and-paste repetitions.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, just letting you know that your solution worked; but without the data module for the function_name

  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_rscheduler.function_name

Comment: @munchine Ah yes. Thanks. I tested the code before making the answer, and forgot to remove `data`. Question was updated to fixed that now.